# Setting monit base URL?

Tags: monit

I run `monit` on several servers, usually proying it via `nginx` as suggested by the monit manual (https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Nginx). That works well on 8 out of 10 servers. But on 2 servers, I encounter issues with the web interface.

Whenever I select a service (e.g. `nginx`) an click the "Enable monitoring" or "Disable monitoring" button, the action is done, but the response redirects (302) to `/nginx` instead of `/monit/nginx`.

As this issue only appears on a few servers (maybe related to Ubuntu 22.04 instead of Ubuntu 20.04), it's a bit hard to track the problem down. Is there an option to tell Monit the base URL to be used for the redirects? Or does it need any more information proxied by `nginx`?

Answer (score 0):

You can not define a base URL in the Monit configuration.

> Is there an option to tell Monit the base URL to be used for the redirects?